# Mapa carrega apenas no meu dispositivo

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, sha1, key-value

Tenho um mapa em um fragmento.
Já resolvi todas como questões de chaves, criei o apk assinado, não é o que eu quero fazer e não coloquei nenhum console de desenvolvedor da google, com o nome do projeto.
Um chave criado coloquei no manifesto do app e criei um novo apk assinado.
Acontece que o mapa não carrega meu celular.
No da minha mãe, assim como abro o fragmento do mapa do erro e o app fecha
Assim como um amigo da minha sala
Ambos copiar o apk assinado e um deles debuguei direto no celular e ainda assim nao funcionou.

Seguir exatamente o que é esse tutorial para a criação da chave http://ninjadevspace.com/mapa-em-uma-aplicacao-android/

O erro que tenho não dispositivo do meu amigo é:
Lembrando que não há nada para o meu celular

> ```
> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.gabi.busk_13_09, PID: 2874
> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
>    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
>    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
>    at Fragments.Fragment_mapa.onCreateView(Fragment_mapa.java:62)
>    at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2229)
>    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973)
>    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148)
>    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793)
>    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535)
>    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:482)
>    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5530)
>    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:733)
>    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:623)
> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
>    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
>    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
>    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
>    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
>    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
>    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
>    at Fragments.Fragment_mapa.onCreateView(Fragment_mapa.java:62) 
>    at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2229) 
>    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973) 
>    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148) 
>    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793) 
>    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535) 
>    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:482) 
>    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
>    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5530) 
>    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:733) 
>    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:623) 
> Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Trying to instantiate a class com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment that is not a Fragment
>    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:608)
>    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:584)
>    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2192)
>    at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:186)
>    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:754)
>    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
>    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
>    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
>    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
>    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
>    at Fragments.Fragment_mapa.onCreateView(Fragment_mapa.java:62) 
>    at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2229) 
>    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973) 
>    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148) 
>    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793) 
>    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535) 
>    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:482) 
>    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
>    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5530) 
>    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:733) 
>    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:623) 
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException
>    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:608) 
>    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:584) 
>    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2192) 
>    at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:186) 
>    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:754) 
>    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
>    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
>    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
>    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
>    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
>    at Fragments.Fragment_mapa.onCreateView(Fragment_mapa.java:62) 
>    at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2229) 
>    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973) 
>    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148) 
>    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793) 
>    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535) 
>    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:482) 
>    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
>    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5530) 
>    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Tente seguir esse tutorial [video Aula](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IukzSur4JyU)
é bem simples de ver a implementação de uma nas versãos 1(v1) e 2(v2) do maps